# Make number format?

Tags: php

Make format of number:

For example:
if number = 204433
output = 204K

if number = 84243
output = 84'243

if number = 8000
output = 8000

if number = 400
output = 400
How to formatted number to that's format?

Comment: Well, use If's to do that. Maybe you want to put that in a function.

Answer (score 3):

The [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) command can do what you are looking for.

> string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )

---

You wrote:

> if number = 84243
>   output = 84'243

Example:

```
$in = 84243;
$out = number_format ( $in, 0, ".", "'");
// $out = "84'243"
```

Comment: That's not the whole requirement though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this

```
if(strlen($number) > 5) {
   echo substr($number,0,2).'K';
} elseif(strlen($number)) {
   echo numberformat($number,2,'.',"'"); // for example
} else {
   echo $number;
}
```